# For an app, do we need a service account for each domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am developing an app that works with Google Calendar API to provide some services to employees of an organization. For that I need access to their calendars to make changes on their behalf. Although OAuth2.0 authentication works fine, I am exploring service account for my application.

With service account I'll need to give domain wide delegation to service account. But I am stuck with a weird question for which I could not find confirmation on web -

If I have multiple clients (organizations with different domains), will I need a separate service account in each of those domains with domain wide delegation, or just one service account in my own domain (where the application resides)?

The latter sounds scary as it can lead to security breach.

Comment: Each domain (workspace account) will need to create a service account and have it configured for it.   I dont think you could use them across domains as they have to be created by that domain.

Comment: how did you work around this?